# How to convert historical rows into columns in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using an Oracle 12c DB.
I have the following table:

```
  accountId      |     totalBalance |   balanceDate   |
      1          |         10       |   01/01/2010    |
      1          |         20       |   01/02/2010    |
      1          |         30       |   01/03/2010    |
      2          |         11       |   10/01/2010    |
      2          |         21       |   10/02/2010    |
      2          |         31       |   10/03/2010    |
```

This table would store the last balance records for the last 3 months for each account, which means each account will have 3 records in the table.
The number of periods is known, in this case is 3. Of course the values of the balance will vary as the months progress, as the table always stores the last three months balances.
What is not known, of course, is the number of accounts.

I would like to create a view which shows the above data as below:

```
  accountId      |     firstMonth   |   secondMonth   | thirdMonth  |
      1          |         10       |       20        |     30      |
      2          |         11       |       21        |     31      |
```

I don't care about the date.

I have seen plenty of similar questions but none quite the same and I cannot figure out how I could implement this.
Does anyone has any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm . . . You want a relative month.  Assuming the month dates are consistent, you can use `months_between()`:

```
select accountId,
       max(case when months_between(last_bd, balance_date) = 2 then totalBalance end) as firstMonth,
       max(case when months_between(last_bd, balance_date) = 1 then totalBalance end) as secondMonth,
       max(case when months_between(last_bd, balance_date) = 0 then totalBalance end) as thirdMonth
from (select max(balanceDate) over (partition by accountId) as last_bd, b.*
      from balances b
     ) b
group by accountId
```